# Error en query update

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Estoy intentando hacer que mediante un `query`, actualice el campo `folio` de la tabla `inventory_list` según el ultimo `numFile` `(id autoincrementable)`.

```
UPDATE inventory_list set folio = 123 WHERE (SELECT max(numFile) from inventory_list)
```

Me genera este error:

> Table 'inventory_list' is specified twice, both as a target for
>   'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Si ejecuto el query de esta manera, actualiza las demás filas:

```
UPDATE inventory_list set folio = 123 WHERE (SELECT max(numFile))
```

Como puedo lograr esto?

Comment: phpmyadmin no es una base de datos

Comment: Esta bien...pero ya lo probe el  query y no funciona igual.

Comment: Pato tenes montones de preguntas sin respuesta aceptada. Tene en cuenta que aceptar respuestas que solucionan el problema es una de las premisas del sitio. Si no cuando la gente las ve, no va a saber si soluciono o no el problema. si encontraste la solucion por vos mismo, ponela. si no, acepta la respuesta que es la solucion al problema.

Comment: Si esta bien :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería ser así, entiendo que la variable por la cual quieres filtrar el update es numFile.

EDITADO -> Esta vez si que parece que funciona dime que te parece

```
UPDATE inventory_list set folio = 123 WHERE numFile = (SELECT max(numFile) from (select * from inventory_list) as newTable)
```

Comment: Ya lo probe en phpMyAdmin y me sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: Cierto no esta funcionando lo reviso, si lo consigo lo edito sino borrare el post

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo....acabo de editar la publicación.

Comment: ponele un as al primer inventory_list

Comment: Funciona perfectamente :o

Comment: Perfecto pues :)